# Why does using pipe '|' terminate the second process, is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: pipe, input, exit, apache-hive

Just to give some context, I'm trying to run this command

```
echo "set hive.execution.engine=tez;" | hive
```

hive terminates as soon as "set hive.execution.engine..." has been entered into the hive interactive shell,

I want to it to stay in the hive interactive shell, but the shell then terminates and I'm back into the normal linux shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It quits as soon as its input ends. So just don't end it:

```
echo "set hive.execution.engine=tez;" | cat - /dev/tty | hive
```

You won't lose any features which wouldn't be there anyway. This works by concatenating `cat`'s stdin *(which is `echo`'s stdout)* with the input from your terminal. It's pretty simple. The other `cat` solution here will work the same way as long as you run it from a top-level interactive shell.

Comment: That works as well, thanks for your help. I'll use this answer as I don't want to leave features.

Answer (score 5):

After the `echo` finishes, the input of `hive` hits end of file, so `hive` terminates.  You will probably get the same effect if you hit <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> in the interactive shell.  Try the following:

```
(echo "set hive.execution.engine=tez;" ; cat ) | hive
```

However, you may lose cursor movement and other nice features of the interactive shell.

**Edit**: a better way is probably to put your `set` command in `~/.hiverc` per [the hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli).

Comment: That's perfect!, worked just as I intended, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following will be of any help, but just in case, it does, I did a little research.

It can be implemented as (not applied on your command)

```
if (signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR) {
  perror(0);
  exit(1);
}
```

But as for `signal`, it is deprecated.

Better may be

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = 0;
if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0) == -1) {
  perror(0);
  exit(1);
}
```

Source and further information:
[Prevent a process from terminating when writing to a broken pipe](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/prevent_a_process_from_terminating_when_writing_to_a_broken_pipe.html)
and
[Ignore SIGPIPE without affecting other threads in a process](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/ignore_sigpipe_without_affecting_other_threads_in_a_process.html)

Comment: It answers another question: how to prevent pipe terminate the **first** process?